# Place text from user input textbox into textbox on a different slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I get the text from a user input in a userform to populate a text box on another slide?

My code for the UserForm1 submit button:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserName$ = TextBox1.Value
    Unload UserForm1
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub
```

I believe that the value typed by the user in the GUI is stored in the variable `UserName$`.

I tried using label boxes and text boxes.

Comment: Declare `UserName` as a public variable with `Public UserName as String` before the first sub or function at the top of the module.  Then you can refer to `UserName` anywhere in the project.  I'd also suggest `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] to help prevent issues like this and others "forcing" you to properly declare & handle your variables, objects, etc...

Comment: Thank you, I’m not sure I understand the Option Explicit portion though. Also, can you please explain how I use the UserName to have the text appear elsewhere?

Comment: I found this code and tried it but it doesn’t do anything:  Private Sub NameVerify()  Dim osh As Shape. Set osh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1). Osh.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = UserName End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much to unpack in your question.  Microsoft has spent the least amount of effort in exposing PowerPoints Object model through VBA.  While using VBA in Access, Excel, Outlook and Word, you can create some amazing solutions; PowerPoint, not so much.

First as ashleedawg suggested, you should add Option Explicit to every Module, Class, and Form Code.  You can set this as the default by clicking on Tools (on the menu), selecting Options, and then checking Require Variable Declaration.

Now create a Module, by clicking Insert from the menu, then select Module.  This will create a new module. In the module, enter `Public UserName As String`. This will now enable the variable UserName to be accessible anywhere throughout the solution.  It's a Global variable if you will.  I usually call a module that contains my gobals `modGobals`.

```
Option Explicit

Public UserName As String
```

Now for your form code.  When you create a text box on a slide, the default name begins with TextBox followed by a space and a number. You're going to want to rename the text box.  To do this, go to the slide view.  On the Ribbon, make sure the File section is showing. At the far right, you'll see an area called Editing with Find, Replace, Select.  Click on Select.  From the drop down menu that appears, click on "Selection Pane..."  The selection pane will appear, and you'll see all the objects on the slide.  When you click on different slide objects, they will be highlighted in the selection pane.

Now that you've renamed your textbox to something like tbUserName, you can update your code as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Private pvSlide As Slide
Private pvShp As Shape

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UserName = TextBox1.Value

    'Assume that slide index 2 contains the text box you want to update
    Set pvSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)

    'set the shape you're going to update
    Set pvShp = pvSlide.Shapes("tbUserName")

    'This is the fun part -- traversing the object tree to get to the
    'right property that so we can update the text box's value
    pvShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = UserName

    Unload UserForm1
    'I'm not sure why you're executing this method.  So I commented it out
    'ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub
```

When you run the user form, enter text into the textbox and press the command button, the text you enter will show up in the text box on slide 2.

Good luck and happy coding

Comment: Thank you again. I’m really struggling with getting this to work. Right now when I click the command button I get a message “Compile error: Variable not defined” and it highlights TextBox1 in the code.

Comment: I’d be happy to share the file with you if that would help. I’m afraid that I put the code where it doesn’t belong or something.

Comment: If the compile error is occurring on `UserName = Textbox1.Value` it's probably because you aren't using the name of the textbox from your input form.  Look at the input form, click on the text box you get the user name from and see what its name property is.  That is the name you want to use for this assignment equation. I recommend you get a book on VBA programming.  Amazon has a bunch.  If you want something that's online you can also (O'Reilly Safari Books Online)[https://www.safaribooksonline.com/].  They have great books, videos, etc. which can help you.

Comment: Thanks, it’s actually highlighting the pvshp.textbox1.textrange.text and stating that the Method or data member not found. I’m wondering if I have to have a specific type of shape to reference. Does it need to be a text box ActiveX control or a regular text box? I’ve tried both. The farthest I’ve gotten is that I get no error but the slide doesn’t advance.

Comment: Have you declared the variable UserName in a module as shown above?  It should compile if you've done that. To advance to the next slide, you need to uncomment the line ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

Comment: Hallelujah! I got it to work! Thank you so much for your help, you rock!

Comment: Just one more question since I tried to duplicate the code for some additional text. Does the UserName = tbUserName.Value still work the same if the tbUserName object is a label instead of an input box? I tried to get the value of a label which is named Percentage with the code Percentage2 = Percentage.Value and did declare Percentage2 as string but it returns Compile error: Variable not defined.  The code for it is Option Explicit

Comment: The code for it is Option Explicit Private pvslide As Slide Private pvshp As Shape Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() Percentage2 = Percentage.Value Set pvslide = ActivePresentation.Slides(34) Set pvshp = pvslide.shapes(“textbox 100”) pvshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Percentage2 Unload UserForm1 End Sub

Comment: In VBA the Textbox control's Text property contains the text entered by the user or placed into it via your code.  The Label control's text is stored in the Caption property.  The Label control does not have a text property.  I highly recommend that you join [O'Reilly's Safari Books Online](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/) or get a book from Amazon on VBA programming.  In addition to books, O'Reilly has blogs and technical training videos.  I like _Programming Excel with VBA: A Practical Real-World Guide_ by Flavio Morgado.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and information. The reason I'm not really that interested in getting a book is that this is a one time thing I'm doing. My mother asked me to help her with a presentation she is making for work and it needed to do specific things. I have a MacBook with Windows installed on a partition and never needed to use it till now (4 years later) so I doubt I'll really need to use coding much after this. Normally I use MacOS and VBS doesn't function there.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you just want to modify previous code.
For that just below `$username = textBox1.value` write down:

```
yourtextBoxname.text = textBox1.text
```